# d_marc send my own emails in spam folders

Tags: dns, cloudflare, roundcube, dmarc

I have a website, with a mailbox using Roundcube. This mailbox is affiliate to my domain name.

I use Cloudflare on my website with a D_marc in DNS section, and this send my own emails as SPAM to anybody.

I don't understand why.

```
v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:contact@sp-batiment.com; ruf=mailto:contact@sp-batiment.com; fo=1
```

whereas I thought it should only send email who are not sent from my domain to SPAM folders.

Comment: Do you have an SPF record configured as well? It should have the IP address or hostname of the sending server. SPF is to authorize any external service to relay through your own domain's SMTP service.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to change p=quarantine to p=none (reporting only) as that won't break your own email. Then, once you have SPF and/or DKIM passing *and* in alignment (using same domain as the visible from) such that DMARC passes for all your legit mail, then cautiously ramp your policy back up to an enforcing policy.

I'd say that changing your policy to none (reporting only) gives the time and space to fix email authentication problems without causing you real problems with your own email deliverability.